# Asynctask alternative without limited amount of tasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to download some thumbnails async in background and load them into an ImageView after download finished. For this purpose I used AsyncTask, but it's not properly working for more then 5 download at the same time. It seems like there is an internal limit of Asynctask running at the same time.
What is the right alternative to have an ulimited amount of background processes which can update the UI after finishing download?

Comment: ???? First you talk about async tasks that download. And then you want processes to update the gui. What is going on?

Comment: An AsyncTask is designed for doing some work in the background and make it possible to update the UI after finishing. Thats not possible with standard threads and will lead in an application crash.

Comment: Thread + `runOnUiThread()`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) anymore as it's deprecated.

I would recommend you to use a suitable library for that use case, such as [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) or [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco), just to mention. Not only they download images but they also handle other tasks like caching or download cancellation.